# Can't get Unit Test Success in SonarQube

Tags: java, unit-testing, sbt, sonarqube

I can't figure out how to get the "Unit Test SUccess" section to appear on my SonarQube dashboard. I've tried setting every sonar and sonar.java I can think of but they just don't appear. I am using the "sbt-sonarrunner-plugin", version 1.0.4, and Jacoco for calculating coverage. Any help would be greatly appreciated, as everything I have found says that settings the sonar.junit.reportsPath property should make it work. For reference I have also tried setting the sonar.test property and it didn't work either.

This is what the unit test widget looks like.

[image]

Here are my properties, the project name and directory are passed in.

```
val commonSonarProperties = Map(
    "sonar.projectName" -> s"$projectName",
    "sonar.junit.reportsPath" -> s"$projectDir/target/test-reports",
    s"$projectName.sonar.sources" -> s"$projectDir/src/main/java",
    "sonar.java.binaries" -> s"$projectDir/target/classes",
    "sonar.java.test" -> s"$projectDir/src/test/java",
    "sonar.java.test.binaries" -> s"$projectDir/target/test-classes",
    "sonar.java.coveragePlugin" -> "jacoco",
    "sonar.jacoco.reportPath" -> s"$projectDir/target/jacoco/jacoco.exec",
    "sonar.jacoco.itReportPath" -> s"$projectDir/target/it-jacoco/jacoco.exec"
)
```

Comment: Did you found reports in $projectDir/target/test-reports? Look at the SonarQube log for relevant error messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out what was going wrong. I noticed in the logs when I ran Sonar with log level set to debug I was getting the following message.

```
- parsing <directory>/target/test-reports
- Reports path contains no files matching TEST-.*.xml : <directory>/target/test-reports
```

I had set my "sonar.junit.reportsPath" correctly, but Sonar was expecting the xml files in my directory to start with "TEST-". When I renamed the xml files to start with TEST- the results then displayed on the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem, where jenkins wasn't able to read the .exec file of jacoco. Upon checking sonar-project.properties i found that these two fields were empty:

```
sonar.junit.reportsPath=
sonar.jacoco.reportPath=
```